# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class ResourceCreateManagerController when creating new page or doing update in modx revolution

Tags: modx

I just wanted to create a new page in modx revolution and I got this error when clicking on plus icon Fatal error: ***Cannot redeclare class ResourceCreateManagerController in*** ....... public_html/manager/controllers/default/resource/update.class.php I could create a new page by clicking on document icon but when I wanted to change the template of this page and update it I got that same error.What I can do please?

Comment: "in ..." - is the most important part of your question. Why delete?

Comment: updated @Vasis.Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: http://forums.modx.com/thread/78892/solved---moved-revo-site---error -  maybe this would help?

Comment: no it didnt help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.I found the code where class was created and add this code aboce Class creation code

```
if (! class_exists('ResourceUpdateManagerController')) {
  create class ResourceUpdateManagerController
}
```

And that's it.

Comment: That's not really a solution, more of a workaround. Something is loading a ResourceUpdateManagerController class in a way that is not compatible with the core. It might be a custom resource type you have recently installed that is a bit too eager.

Comment: I searched a lot but havent found that.Even dowloaded all files and searched within with Dreamviewer but no result.So for now it solved my issue @Mark Hamstra!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when my `config.inc.php` had different base paths for the different constants (`MODX_CORE_PATH`, `MODX_PROCESSORS_PATH`). This is an artifact of how we manage this file.

Bringing all those into alignment (where they all had the same base path) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you uninstall or update an extra recently? check your plugins to see if one of them is trying to do something while managing resources.  your logs should provide more clies than just the error.

Comment: I have started to bulit my website on the latest version of modx - modx revolution